# Hacerse al héroe

Tags: méxico, sinónimos

I have heard the following sentence in the Narcos:Mexico TV series:

> No le haga al héroe por un pinche muerto.

I know that "hacerse el héroe" = to play hero / to be a hero, but this is the first time I see "hacerse *al* héroe. I assume both have the same meaning. Is the latter also usual? Is it a Mexican regionalism ?

Answer (score 1):

Here, the most accurate translation means:

> Don't try to play hero over a ... dead man.

There are 2 ways to say the same here:

> **Hacerse el** héroe
>
> **Hacerle al** héroe

I don't find any significant difference in meaning for those 2 expressions. It's just regionalisms, as you have stated correctly.

It's just 2 different ways to express the same idea, but the first would mean trying to be a hero, and the second trying to impersonate a hero. Both have the same meaning in that context. So I think it is just a matter of how you want to use it.

**No le haga al** is a negative imperative form of **Hacerle al**

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not a regionalism, it's actually used in Spain too. It means as you said, to play a hero /act like a hero.

Comment: Notice that it's "hacerse al héroe" and not "hacerse el héroe", so it seems to be something different (in fact, I've never heard "hacerse al éroe").

Comment: Me neither, that's why I assumed it's just a mistake and he meant to say hacerse el heroe